# Combobox selected values display in the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, combobox

Using C# & MySQL

In my web page am using Comboxbox, if am selecting the value from the combobox the selected values should display in the gridview......

Code

```
cmd2 = new OdbcCommand("Select * from tb_car where vehicleno = '" + cmbvnoview.SelectedValue + "' ", con);
        ada2 = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd2);
        ds1 = new DataSet();
        ada2.Fill(ds1);
        vhviewgrid.DataSource = ds1;
        vhviewgrid.DataBind();
```

Above Code is working properly, but I don't know in which event i have to write a code for display

Need C# Code Help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your code in [OnSelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event and mark

```
AutoPostBack="true"
```

in combox tag..

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cmbvnoview" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbvnoview_SelectedIndexChanged">     </asp:DropDownList>

protected void cmbvnoview_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  cmd2 = new OdbcCommand("Select * from tb_car where vehicleno = '" + cmbvnoview.SelectedValue + "' ", con);
  ada2 = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd2);
  ds1 = new DataSet();
  ada2.Fill(ds1);
  vhviewgrid.DataSource = ds1;
  vhviewgrid.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should execute this in the `cmbvnoview.SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ComboBox [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event.

Comment: I used the SelectedIndexChanged event, nothing changing

Comment: Care to update your question with the "new" source code for the SelectedIndexChanged event?

Answer (score 1):

It will resolve your problem

**Design:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1"    runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
           onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
       </asp:DropDownList>
       <br />
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
           <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#99CCFF" />
       </asp:GridView>
```

**Code:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JEL-PC\\SQLSERVER2008;Initial Catalog=Jel;user id=sa;password=jel_2004;");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from employee", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        ViewState["ds"] = ds;
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();

        DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "ename";

        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "eid";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string x = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        int index=0;
        DataSet ds=new DataSet();

        ds=(DataSet)ViewState["ds"];

        for(int i=0;i<ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++)
        {
            if(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString()==x)
            {
                index=i;
                Response.Write(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString()+" i="+i);
            }
        }

        GridView1.SelectedIndex = index;


    }
```